# Вопрос по html - подсказка

Tags: html, css

Когда я пробую создать подсказку для картинки, она все равно не показывается. В чем моя проблема?

```
<div class="left-top">
        <img src="0-wrz2aMMyY.jpg" title='Самолет'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `title` показывается лишь по наведению на картинку. Также для `img` является обязательным атрибут `alt` – он показывается, если картинка не загрузилась, а также нужен для SEO и людей с ограниченными возможностями.

Если хотите добавить подсказку, которая будет видна всегда, используйте такую конструкцию:

```html
<figure class="left-top">
    <img src="https://1000.tech/img/bg0.jpg" title='Самолет'>
    <figcaption>Самолет</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: но у меня при наведение и не работает)

Comment: @Halland тут надо ваши стили смотреть и код в целом. Возможно перекрывает блок какой-то картинку, или где-то на родителе стоит pointer-events: none.

Comment: Да, я понял) У меня другие перекрывают. Большое тебе спасибо)

Comment: @Halland не за что)